# How to Save Email from inbox to local drive as .msg file?

Tags: vba, outlook

```vb
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk()
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SaveFolder As String 
    
    SaveFolder = "D:\Test"
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
     
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    For Each oMail in Inbox.Items
        oMail.SaveAs SaveFolder, olMSG
    
End Sub
```

I want to move emails to the local drive as a .msg file.

Answer (score 1):

The path in which to save the item should include the file name, for example:

```
Sub SaveAsTXT()
    Dim myItem As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim objItem As Object
    
    Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector
    
    If Not TypeName(myItem) = "Nothing" Then
        Set objItem = myItem.CurrentItem
        strname = objItem.Subject
        
        'Prompt the user for confirmation
        Dim strPrompt As String
        strPrompt = "Are you sure you want to save the item? " & _
                    "If a file with the same name already exists, " & _
                    "it will be overwritten with this copy of the file."
        
        If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
            objItem.SaveAs Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\My Documents\" & strname & ".txt", olTXT
        End If
        Else
            MsgBox "There is no current active inspector."
    End If
End Sub
```

Or in your code:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk()
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim ns As Namespace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SaveFolder As String
    
    SaveFolder = "D:\Test"
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    For Each oMail In Inbox.Items
        oMail.SaveAs SaveFolder & oMail.Subject & ".msg", olMSG
    Next oMail
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk()

    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem, ns As NameSpace, Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SaveFolder As String, i As Integer
    
    SaveFolder = "D:\Test\"
    
    If Dir(SaveFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Check the save folder path", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    Else
        Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        
        For Each oMail In Inbox.Items
            oMail.SaveAs SaveFolder & "MailItemNo_" & i & ".msg", OlSaveAsType.olMSG
            ' You can use oMail.Subject as a filename instead MailItemNo_, 
            ' but it's need to be removed prohibited characters from it previously 
            ' and control unique of the filename
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```